# Relying on more than a single Observable in a template in Angular app

Tags: angular, redux, observable

We are using redux for almost everything in our app.
Usually, when we use a data fetched from the app state we keep it as Observable and using Observable in the component's template.

for example:

```
*ngFor="let project of projects$ | async"
```

What is the correct way to do it, if we have a component with two (or more) Observables? Especially, when we use the data from both:
Iterating on one list and when rendering, fetching some of the details from another?

I am aware that I can subscribe for the changes in component for all sets of data, store it in a separate variable in the controller and use that in the template. But, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way that does not require unwrapping the observables.

Here is a more specific example:
I have a controller:

```
export class PrincipleComponent implements OnInit {

  @select(['principleList', 'principles'])
  principles$: Observable<Principle[]>;

  @select(['domainPrincipleList', 'domainPrinciples'])
  domainPrinciples$: Observable<DomainPrinciple[]>;

  columnsToDisplay = ['id', 'title', 'description'];

  constructor(private principleActions: PrincipleActions,
              private domainPrincipleActions: DomainPrincipleActions,
              private domainActions: DomainActions) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.principleActions.loadPrinciples();
    this.domainPrincipleActions.loadDomainPrinciples();
    this.domainActions.loadDomains();
  }

}
```

And in the template, I am trying to iterate through the principles and inside each iteration use information available in domainPrinciples:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let principle of principles$ | async" class="principle-card">
      {{principle.name}}
      // Here I need to use some data coming from the domainPrinciples$ Observable
  </mat-card>
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently, I have no idea how to achieve what I need:
So, in my controller I have:

```
selectedDomainId: number = null;

  @select(['principleList', 'principles'])
  principles$: Observable<Principle[]>;

  @select(['domainList', 'domains'])
  domains$: Observable<Domain[]>;

  @select(['domainPrincipleList', 'domainPrinciples'])
  domainPrinciples$: Observable<DomainPrinciple[]>;
```

Then in the template that I started to build:

```
<div fxLayout="column"
     fxLayoutAlign="space-between stretch"
     fxLayoutGap="5px"
     class="fp-principles-list"
     *ngIf="{ domains: domains$ | async, principles: principles$ | async, domainPrinciples: domainPrinciples$ | async } as values;">

  <h1 class="mat-headline title">40 Principles Settings</h1>
  <h2 class="mat-subheader title">
    Principles for
    <small>
      <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'never'" class="domain-selector">
        <mat-select placeholder="Generic definitions" [(ngModel)]="selectedDomainId" name="domain">
          <mat-option>
            Generic definitions
          </mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let domain of values.domains" [value]="domain.id">
            {{domain.title}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </small>
  </h2>

  <table mat-table [dataSource]="values.principles" class="mat-elevation-z4">

    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="td-id"> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="td-title"> {{element.title}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        Description
      </th>
      <td colspan="2" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="td-description" [innerHTML]="element.description"></td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

`DomainPrinciple` object:

```
export class DomainPrinciple {
  id?: number;
  description?: string;
  domain?: IdRef;
  principle?: IdRef;
  createdBy: IdRef;
  dateCreated: Moment;
  updatedBy?: IdRef;
  lastUpdated?: Moment;
}
```

The problem is, when user changes the selected domain (in dropdown), I need to resolve `description` based on selected domain from the list of domainPrinciples.

The only option that I see, is to create a function and pass in `principle`, selected domain and the whole list of domain principles as arguments and resolve the description based on this.

But, that feels wrong... I feel like it should be done through redux, but I am not sure how.

Comment: please give an example to clarify the needs of your work

Comment: @Fartab added an example

Comment: your question is not clear. i can't understand what you want. you need data coming from the domainPrinciples$, so subscribe to it by using async pipe.

Comment: you said you look for an elegant way that does not require unwrapping the observable. but the observable has been created for unwrapping at the needed place.

Comment: Finally, I found an easy to understand article explaining exactly what I need: https://coryrylan.com/blog/subscribing-to-multiple-observables-in-angular-components